# Fondo de 2 colores para layout en android

Tags: android

¿Como puedo dejar un fondo de dos colores por igual al 50% sin efectos de degradado?

[image: Algo así como esta imagen]

Comment: César especifica en tu pregunta que es ese fondo? es un layout? es el fondo de una activity?, por favor añade detalles y obtendrás la ayuda requerida. Mira [ask], un saludo!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un archvio en el directorio drawable con el nombre que quieras (puede ser fondo) y pegas el siguiente codigo

```
<item>
    <shape>

        <gradient
            android:centerX="0"
            android:endColor="#9A59B5"
            android:startColor="#8D44AD"
            android:type="sweep" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Ahora al elemento que se lo quieras aplicar simplemente le colocas el background  de la siguiente forma (en el xml)

```
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
```

El archivo fondo.xml esta creando una gradiante pero tipo "sweep" la cual inicia desde un punto y termina en ese mismo punto, con el valor centerX="0" se mueve el punto de inicio (de la gradiante) al inicio del eje x.

[image: Gradient tipo sweep]

Si cambias el valor de 0 o lo eliminas veras la gradiante original.
Espero te sirva y un saludo

Comment: Gracias! aunque el color no se ve 100% liso me servirá de momento.

Comment: Prueba cambiando el valor de centerX por -1 o valores mas bajos para que el centro sea mas lejos y no se noten las lineas pequeñas.

Comment: Va excelente, muchas gracias!